# Internet.Org participation of website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, web

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/platform-technical-guidelines

I have read this link and understood what internet. Org requires for a website to be eligible for free.

Now I have a website which is content heavy and DON'T Meet any of their requirements. But somehow I managed to make a light version of my website. But there is one problem.

If someone visits `www.mysite.com/home.php` they are viewing the heavy version of site. On the other hand if someone visits `www.mysite.com/homelight.php` they are viewing the light version of site. Now I don't want people to use different links to browse through light or heavy version. I want them only to use the first link and detect whether they are using freebasics from Internet. Org and based on that show them heavy or light version.

I thought of using `user_agent` to detect client device but it won't help as people can use freebasics from desktops or they wanna use heavy version on mobile.

Anyone has any solutions?

Comment: The Page states `All requests that pass through the Internet.org proxy will contain internet.org in the Via HTTP header field.`, so try checking for it in headers.

Comment: For better user experience, why don't you create a subdomain such as `light.mysite.com`, so it is very easy to handle all situations.

Comment: Does making subdomain costs extra for hosting?

Comment: Depends on your web host. Which web host are you currently using?

Comment: Haven't hosted yet looking for cheap fast unlimited root access hosting.

Comment: There are many free hosts, and most of them provide 5 free subdomains. Some of the popular ones are 000webhost and hostinger.